# How do I move the position of the Open Weather extension in the top bar?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, top-bar

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with the Open Weather extension. The indicator is in the center of the top bar, but I see screen shots with it moved to the right. How do I do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide another way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The position of the status menu can be adjusted via the `Open Weather` GNOME Shell extension preferences which can either be found in the `gnome-tweak-tool`'s `Extension` section with a click of the little cog next to the listed extension or by clicking the settings icon in the status menu:

[image: Open Weather settings button]

And then changing `Position in Panel` to `Right` in the `Layout` tab:

[image: Open Weather Layout preferences]

**Option 2:**

*(As we already established that you have this add-on installed in chat.)* You can use the [Extend Status Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/) GNOME Shell extension for this. Which can be installed following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819).

The order of the status menus can be changed via the extension's settings which can be found if one clicks the status menu with the username and then the option labelled `Extension Settings`:

[image: Extension Settings button in menu]

Then one may use the `Up` and `Down` buttons to adjust the order of the status menus:

[image: Up and Down buttons in extension preferences]

Comment: Whoa. I never noticed that option before. Thanks.

Comment: @chaskes: You're welcome! ;)

Comment: You have to install the `Extend Panel Menu` extension to do what @ParanoidPanda recommends.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I didn't see any chat, or that extension mentioned in your answer, so I assumed that I needed to point that out.

Comment: @heynnema: I have updated my answer to include another way of doing it through the originally mentioned extension instead.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you're so smart. +1 vote